# Trying to select all records where a change has been made from the previous year

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of courses: c_inst, c_year, c_program_type, c_unique_key. I want to find where the c_program_type has changed from 'V' to 'P' and vice versa from 2016 to 2017. I have having issues getting this to run. Here is what i've tried and I know it's just flat out wrong:

```
 select * from courses a 
 where c_program_type in ('P','V') 
 and c_year = '2017' 
 and c_program_type != (select c_program_type from courses b where   
                       a.c_unique_key = b.c_unique_key and c_year = '2016')
```

What is the easiest way to do this for a sql noob? I've also tried using sql server temp tables, but haven't had luck there. Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you switch rows between 'V' and 'P', do you update an existing row or add a new one? If it's the latter, how do you flag that the old row is now obsolete?

Comment: Are P and V the only permitted values for `c_program_type` or are there more possibilities?

Comment: There are more possibilities for c_program_type, but I'm looking specifically at P and V.

Comment: We do not update the existing row, but we do add a new record when we get them from institutions and that's why we are trying to check when these program types have changed if that makes sense. I know there is a better way to flag that the old row is now obsolete, but this is the only way I can validate the data at this point

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM   courses a 
       LEFT JOIN courses b 
              ON a.c_unique_key = b.c_unique_key 
                 AND a.c_program_type = b.c_program_type 
                 AND b.c_year = '2016' 
WHERE  a.c_program_type IN ( 'P', 'V' ) 
       AND a.c_year = '2017' 
       AND b.c_unique_key IS NULL
```